# How to use java doc and class

Tags: java

I am learning java. I have no previous knowledge in java. I am kind of lost when I open java doc for help. Although everything seems very organized but im just learning programming in java. In java doc I can see every java package has some class and each class has some methods. For example, "io" package has a class "File" and it has a method "getName". Now in the method implementation only `public String getName()` this line of code is given. I don't understand how can I use it. Do I have to import the package first and then use an object of the class to access the method? or how can I use the method?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 3):

All the classes are in a packages. So, first you have to import the class

```
import java.io.File;
```

Then you can instance it.

```
String fileName = "/tmp/user/file.txt";
File d = new File(fileName);
```

Now, you can use the getName method

```
String fName = d.getName();
```

You can check, also, the following [examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The methods are specific to the class that they are inside so if you would like to access the method you would need an instance of the class so that you could use it.

```
File file = new File("Some file path");
file.getName();//This will return the name of the file
```

Most IDE's will recognize usable classes and allow you to right click the class and import the necessary package to use that class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

> Now in the method implementation only `public String getName()` this
>   line of code is given

is not true. I guess you are not reading the "implementation codes",  instead, you are reading the javaDoc, there you cannot see the implementation of a method.

For your example, you have to first `import java.io.File`, then create a `File` object, say `file`, then you can `file.getName()` to call the method. I suggest that you find some java tutorial and first read it, then write some "helloworld" like codes, so that you know the fundamental building blocks and how do they work.

Answer (score 0):

The `getName`  method is defined inside the `File` class which is available in the `java.io` package.

To use the file class you first need to import it with

```
import java.io.File;
```

`getName` is an instance method. To use it, you need to call it on an instance of file. You can create a new file using

```
File myFile = new File(...);
```

There is more than one way of creating a instance of the `File` class. These are described in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-). The easiest way of creating an instance of the `File` class is to pass it a path like this:

```
File myFile = new File("path/to/your/file");
```

You can call the `getName` method like so

```
myFile.getName();
```

The official java docs are more references than anything else. You might be better off following a tutorial.